# SMS Thread / General Limit?

Tags: sms

Is there a limit within Android, or possibly set by OEMs (heard this from a friend who is a technician), of the total amount of SMS messages you can have? As in, messages within a thread  and/or all threads combined? Not just the limit within conversations which you can manually set. I mean a limit android has coded into it, or one that OEMs set, that actually would "limit" (whether by slowing down or stopping) the number of SMS you can have?

And I'm not talking about a couple thousand, but even in the hundreds of thousands in a thread?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot provide a definitive answer, but some folks have had over 20,000 messages, based on this [Reddit discussion](http://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/sceja/android_maximum_sms_limit_of_5000_messages/). So if there are any limits, it may have been set by the OEM (or their custom app). Using 3rd-party SMS apps might provide a workaround to the limit.

I would bet that if are hundreds of thousands of messages, there could be a significant performance issue, although that may depend on how the app processes the records. Go SMS Pro, for example, does not load the messages all at once. But if it reaches the point where it has loaded already a lot of messages, the app slows down.

**UPDATE #1:** To paraphrase Izzy, the storage limit will also trigger the "insufficient memory" error, usually when there's less than ~25 MB free space on internal storage. This would also prevent the SMS from being stored (plus the possibility to send some on your own).

Comment: Well, I have ALMOST 100,000 SMS in one thread. I currently use Hangouts with the new SMS integration, but previously had to use GoSMS. GoSMS would be a little sluggish, and annoying. But, in the stock SMS app, I could load it one time, tap the big thread, and it wouldn't load. Then when I went back to the thread view, it wouldn't load. I don't want to delete them, and I won't. Just wondering why that happens, and if there is a limit in Android/OEMs.

Also: I am rooted running a CM 10.1.

Comment: @David I would assume this would be more of a hardware issue. On a PC, just try opening a really large text file (maybe 2-5GB) on Notepad, on an average PC. I think it would crash.

Comment: I thought of that as well. Is there an app, that you know of, that would, cache x amount of the messages, only loading them if specifically called upon? Like if I kept scrolling up in the conversation, and hit a "load more" option? That seems like a simple enough fix for large SMS threads, no?

Comment: @David I have no idea. You'd have to check the play store for that. 100K seems overkill to me though. I normally delete my conversations after some time, or back-up those that are important to me.

Comment: well yeah I could always backup and store somewhere. But I haven't found a solution for that which I like, yet. I just think, that even how absurd the message count is, the app should be able to handle it. Every message already sent or received won't change, so there is no need to load the first x amount of messages after a thread hits x length.

Comment: One more thing to keep in mind (geff, you might wish to include that directly with your answer) is the storage limit triggering the "insufficient memory" error. If I remember correctly, that would also prevent SMS from being stored (plus the possibility to send some on your own). This error is triggered usually when there's less than ~25 MB free space on internal storage.

Comment: @Izzy no it isn't. It just REALLY lags the phone / stock SMS app. I have over 10 GB free on my internal SD card (no external slot). I never get the memory issue, just the lag.

Comment: @David I think the phone can only handle so much (think of PC RAM vs hard disk)

Comment: @David I didn't mean to say this has to be the reason *in your case* (and I'm sure geff didn't understand it that way either). We were just completing the list *in general*, as for a future visitor this might be the crucial point. And it *could* have been a point in your case, so we wanted to make sure you know it and eventually can either rule it out. Besides: the internal card is of no interest for it, neither is the external card. **The `insufficient memory` error is only related to *phone storage*** (aka "internal storage"), not to any SD/external storage.

Comment: @Izzy Oh okay. Just thought you might have meant that was happening to me. But do you think an SMS app, designed (probably on some simple function) to cache a certain number of messages and not load them, would alleviate my problems?

Comment: @David Sure, why not? [But ASE is not a programming site. That would be better off in StackOverflow]